# is there a way to unify the direction of edges or assign them a direction?

Tags: mesh, optimization

basically I want to find out a way to set the same direction to a selection of edges having almost the same direction like in picture 
(to select them all I select one, press shift + G and choose direction)

[image]the result i want to reach[image]
And is it possible with an object who isn't a plane[image]

Comment: You could scale the edges to a specific axis by zero. Select the edges you want to straighten, press S, X(or any other axis) and then 0.

Comment: correct, but that's too long if I have to do it for every edges (because if i select all of them like in picture 1 they will all be straight but in the same location)

Comment: Try changing the pivot point to 'Individual origin'